# How to Allow apostrophe and space for validation

Tags: yii

```
array(
      'user_mname,user_lname,user_fname',
      'match' ,
      'pattern'=>'/^[A-Za-z_]+$/u',
      'message'=>"{attribute} contains not allowed characters"
     ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this:

```
'pattern'=>'/^[A-Za-z_\s\']+$/u',
```