# Want to store special characters like Apostrophe etc.. in yii model->save()

Tags: php, yii

i need to store special chanraters in my model save,
my `$model->attributes` is like following

```
Array
(
    [name] => Indian Identity
    [description] => Description from 'Ranjit Hoskote’s The Complicit Observer provides an art-historical account of Sudhir Patwardhan’s career, which spans over three decades and ranges across painting, drawing, township. 
    [clsfication] => this is classification 
   )
```

how to store the special characters with `model->save()` ,

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248473/how-to-allow-apostrophe-and-space-for-validation

Comment: You should edit the question and post your real code, together with the specific issue you're facing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP native function [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Code:

```
$model->setAttributes([
   'name' => addslashes('name'),
   'description' => addslashes('description'),
   'clsfication' => addslashes('clsfication'),
]);
$model->save();
```

Comment: is there anyway to add 'addslashes' to all fields in the form dynamically

Answer (score 0):

```
Array
(
    [name] => Indian Identity
    [description] => Description from 'Ranjit Hoskote\'s The Complicit Observer provides an art-historical account of Sudhir Patwardhan\'s career, which spans over three decades and ranges across painting, drawing, township.' 
    [clsfication] => this is classification 
   )
```

try this. and let me know if it is working.

Comment: the description is the dynamic one , get from client